# Software updates after upgrading kernel

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I recently upgraded the kernel to 4.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.. Will future software updates break the system? Do I need to revert back if I need software and security updates?

Comment: What kind of break are you talking about? Is this about package manager dependencies, or something else?

Comment: I highly doubt it.